# Program works fine, but gives the wrong answer

Tags: python

I am working on project euler challenge 22 -

Using names.txt (right click and 'Save Link/Target As...'), a 46K text file containing over five-thousand first names, begin by sorting it into alphabetical order. Then working out the alphabetical value for each name, multiply this value by its alphabetical position in the list to obtain a name score.

For example, when the list is sorted into alphabetical order, COLIN, which is worth 3 + 15 + 12 + 9 + 14 = 53, is the 938th name in the list. So, COLIN would obtain a score of 938 × 53 = 49714.

What is the total of all the name scores in the file?

but whenever I try to input the answer I get the site say that it is the wrong answer, I would rather not have the answer, but if you could give me some tip on how to fix my program, or even what I should look up, I would really appreciate it.

Here is my code -

```
Names_File = open("names.txt", "r+").read()
Names = []
Name_Start = ''
name =''
count=0
total = 0

def Value(word,place):
    ABC_Value={'A':1,'B':2, 'C':3, 'D':4, 'E':5, 'F':6, 'G':7, 'H':8, 'I':9, 'J':10, 'K':11, 'L':12, 'M':13, 'N':14, 'O':15, 'P':16, 'Q':17, 'R':18, 'S':19, 'T':20, 'U':21, 'V':22, 'W':23, 'X':24, 'Y':25, 'Z':26}
    number = 0
    place+=1
    for i in word:
        number += ABC_Value[i]
    return number * place

def Clean_Up(Names_File):
    global name
    for i in Names_File:
        if i == '"':
            pass
        elif i==',':
            Names.append(name)
            name = ''
        else:
            name = name + i

Clean_Up(Names_File)
Names = sorted(Names)

while count < len(Names):
    total += Value(Names[count],count)
    count+=1


print(total)
```

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Why don't you make a small file (say 3 names only) that you can manually calculate the correct answer for, and test your program against it? Then you can debug it and see where the calculation goes wrong.

Comment: A program that gives the wrong answer is ***NOT*** working fine. That's like saying my C code is perfect because it compiled, but I just can't understand why it then crashes.

Comment: @paxdiablo I mean that when I test it again the example, COLIN, it gives me the correct answer, and when I only have it run through the first couple of names it gives me the right answer.

Comment: @Milikeye, I am curious, please tell if the code above works. thanks

Comment: @WajdiFarhani it kind of works, when I run it against a single name, or a small group of names it works fine, but once the name file gets too long it doesn't give the right answer anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the assumption that every name is written in new line within your file, this should work

```py
import string

alphab = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
sorted_names_list  = open("names.txt").read().splitlines()
sorted_names_list.sort()  
score = 0
for position,name in enumerate(sorted_names_list):
    alphabetic_score = [alphab.index(letter.lower()) for letter in list(name)]
    score+=position*sum(alphabetic_score)
print score
```

Comment: What about if each name isn't on a different line, the way the file is they are all together like this - "MARY","PATRICIA","LINDA","BARBARA","ELIZABETH","JENNIFER","MARIA","SUSAN","MARGARET","DOROTHY"

Comment: Just change `sorted_names_list  = open("names.txt").read().splitlines()` by `sorted_names_list  = open("names.txt").read().split(',')`

Comment: I tried this, but it brings up the error                                                               <listcomp>
    alphabetic_score = [alphab.index(letter.lower()) for letter in list(name)]
ValueError: '"' is not in list

Comment: yes, that's because names are splitted by `","` not `,` so this should work `sorted_names_list = open("names.txt").read().split('","')`

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you want to do:

```
Names = [l.strip() for l in open("names.txt", "rU")]
```

instead of your current first two lines. This will read the names file into a list of lines instead of a sequence of characters.

Comment: Does it really matter, wouldn't it have the same result either way? Also, what does "rU" mean?

Comment: One way you'll have each character in the file as an item in the list, the other you'll have each line in the file, i.e. the difference between ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'...] and ['abcd', 'defg', 'bob', 'harry'] etc. 'rU' means use universal newline support so it doesn't matter what platform the file was saved on.